# Sharepoint 2010 Trial period has expired

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using sharepoint 2010 but I am facing

```
Tail period has expired 

http://ceekam.com/blog/?p=519
```

I had already tried this but it didnt work for me

but now the error changes for me now it becomes Unexpected error has occurred as I change my site collection web config configuration for showing proper error it says object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Web.config files are for the entire application, not just for a single site collection.

Typically, when I see an error stating "object reference not set to an instance of an object", it boils down to order of operations within custom code (which could include javascript, etc).  If you look at the stack trace, you might discover exactly what the issue is.